# Prevent H2O from writing to tmp file

Tags: storage, h2o, tmp

I am kicking off an H2O cluster on a server via the command line. The documentation says H2O needs space in the /tmp directory to write to. Is there a way to make h2o write to a different directory other than /tmp? For reference here is the documentation and the python code I use to launch h2o via command line with an os.system() call:

https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/8/docs-website/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html

```
# Define string to be passed to command line to spin up cluster
h2o_init_command = (
    "nohup java " 
    "-Xmx{cluster_mem_size} "
    "-jar {jar_file} "
    "-nthreads {cluster_threads} "
    "-name {cluster_port} " 
    "-port {cluster_port} " 
    "-ice_root {ice_root_file} " 
    "-hash_login "
    "-login_conf {authentication_file} " 
    "> {nohup_file} &"
    ).format(cluster_mem_size=cluster_mem_size, 
           jar_file=p.JAR_FILE, 
           cluster_threads=cluster_threads,
           cluster_port=cluster_port,
           ice_root_file=p.ICE_ROOT_FILE, 
           authentication_file=p.AUTHENTICATION_FILE, 
           nohup_file=nohup_file
            )

# Start an H2O cluster
return_cde = os.system(h2o_init_command)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if I recall, the way to do this is via by setting the -ice_root path.  This is what the h2o-on-hadoop launch path does.  Not much goes there, just some small log files.  No big data.  So even if you have a small /tmp, it's probably fine to just leave it.

Comment: The ice_root path seems to redirect some types of log files but not all of them. Even when setting ice_root to a different location. H2O is producing folders in the /tmp directory that look like the examples below. The issue is that if /tmp is ever full, it prevents H2O from even starting in the first place: tmppnjcsy09
tmppotv7bq7
tmpq6qnjq8t
tmptkeiujzp
tmpud_oc1x0
tmpvish6c5r
tmpwldy9f6b
tmpwt3z99ss
tmpy34xsomx
tmpypbdfie3
tmpzi0tvkla

Comment: `ice_root` is not working for me. When I don't specify it, using `h2o.init()`, h2o will use `tempdir()` as the layover location when I'm writing to S3, which is good. If I do specify `ice_root`, h2o uses `/tmp` as the layover location.

The problem is, when I launch h2o on another server using the CLI, `tempdir()` on my driver doesn't exist on the remote server. I have specified `ice_root` in this case to a location that is visible by driver and remote server. Still though, it writes to `/tmp` which is not good.